# how to use a variable for dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function to which I am passing column names as parameters. How to I use that variable as dataframe column name?

Dataframe:

```
**Name**
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

```
def print_name(x):
    print(df(x))

print_name('Name')
```

I want to pass dataframe column name as an argument to a function. Is this doable?

Comment: Use square brackets: `df[x]`? It's unclear what you really want to do

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know DataFrames, but can you pre define the name to index of the column, so that you can use like df(name_index_dict[name])

Comment: This is incorrect. `df` will still not be callable...